# Change a li tag class depending on the page the user is in

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a menu and I want to put bold in the menu li depending the page I'm in.

I'm currently doing it like this

```
<li><%= link_to 'Home', users_path, class: "#{'font-bold' if current_page?('/users')}" %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user), class: "#{'font-bold' if !current_page?('/users') && (current_page?(controller: 'profiles', action: 'show') || current_page?(controller: 'profiles', action: 'edit'))}" %></li>
```

but for example if I go to `/users/new` it throws an error
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}`

I guess I could continue adding conditions but this feels like a terrible way to do this.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So the error you see occurs because it seems like your missing a `profiles_controller` or the show action inside of it.

For your question:
I would only play around a bit with the conditions, to shorten your if statement, or you could try to use a view helper.